# Very High Load Time of Sectioned UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uitableview

```
- (NSArray *)dataSourceForIndividuals:(NSArray *)individuals {
  // Assumption: displayNames are sorted alphabetically
  NSUInteger sectionIndexTitlesCount = [[self sectionIndexTitles] count];
  NSMutableArray *dataSource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionIndexTitlesCount];
  NSUInteger index = 0;
  for (index = 0; index < sectionIndexTitlesCount; index++) {
      [dataSource addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
  }
  SEL selector = @selector(displayName);
  index = 0;
  for (TDTIndividual *individual in individuals) {
      NSInteger sectionNumber = [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForObject:individual collationStringSelector:selector];
      [[dataSource objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionNumber] addObject:individual.objectID];
      ++index;
  }
  return dataSource;
}
```

The above code works fine, but time taken by second for loop is too high if number of individuals is large, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know your data structure or what operations are you using in some methods. It would be good if you could measure the comulative time some functions are using. You can have an idea in [instruments](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments--mobile-9403) or [measure that in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773654/code-to-measure-exact-execution-time-inside-code-on-ipad-or-phone).

Nevertheless, maybe you can iterate over your `[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation]` and add the objects through that. Probably will be more efficient than checking for each object what section it corresponds to.

Comment: @MartinR you are completely right. Although that was never the issue :p. I can't remember why I had that idea. I have read both posts a long time ago and I got that idea. Thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Tiago-Almeida points out, we don't know anything about your data structures. Nor do we know what you mean by a "large" number of individuals. And his tip to use Instruments to see where the time is going is very valid.

However, the thing that leaps to my mind is that one of the reasons that the table view works the way it to allow the data source to lazy load its data. If you have a large number of individuals it may be prohibitive to load them into a giant array of arrays up front.

So you could either:

- Modify your backing data structures so that it doesn't require iterating the entire list to sort them into sections every time you need the table view. Frankly, this approach is my first instinct as if I knew that the number of individuals may be large I wouldn't want to be iterating the entire list repeatedly. Perhaps you could modify your getters/setters to automatically maintain these section arrays so that they are already present when you need them?
- Do some of the work asynchronously. Load a manageable number of individuals, create a non-mutable copy of the arrays to use as the data source (make sure to make a deep copy), and then do the rest of the work in the background. Then periodically update the data source with a new non-mutable copy and calling refreshData on the main thread.

Obviously the asynchronous approach isn't ideal, as the table could "jump around" on the user, especially if they try to scroll the table right away. But if there is no other choice, and the total load time is still manageable, then it is a much better experience for the user than just blocking until the entire array is sorted/loaded.